# How to POST xml in php (with c# example)

Tags: c#, php, web-services

I'm trying to explain to a php developer how to consume our web service. There is a bit of a language barrier, but essentially it works by POSTing xml data straight to a url. Here's how you do it in C#, which works just fine;

```
public string POSTXml(string xml, string url)
{
    WebRequest req = null;
    WebResponse rsp = null;
    try
    {
        StringBuilder strRequest = new StringBuilder();                       

        req = WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "POST";        
        req.ContentType = "text/xml";     

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
        writer.WriteLine(xml);
        writer.Close();

        rsp = req.GetResponse();

        var sr = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream());
        string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();

        return responseText;

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("There was a problem sending the message");
    }
}
```

The developer is having trouble doing this in php. Is anyone able to translate the above code into php?

Also, I inherited this code from my predecessor and if I'm being honest I've never seen a web service implented in this way... I'm starting to worry that it's me not explaining it very well (I just tell people to POST the xml straight to the url i give them, and around 80% of them get it straight away and the other 20% get confused!). Is anyone able to give me a better explanation that more people might understand?

Comment: This will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898294/make-a-post-request

Comment: It's a whole can of worms in php opening a socket and stuff like that.  He should try to do it with curl. See here: http://davidwalsh.name/execute-http-post-php-curl

Comment: yeah he's said he's trying to use curl, but he can't get it working. I've googled it for him and asked him to try some code but I'm not really a php developer so it's very hit and hope!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
<?php

// Some code borrowed from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php
$url = 'http://www.example.com/';
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?><data>x</data>';

try
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    // set URL and other appropriate options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: close'));
    curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_errno($ch))
    {
        throw new Exception(curl_errno($ch) . ': ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    else
    {
        $result = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($returnCode == 404)
        {
            throw new Exception('URL Invalid');
        }
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result;
}
catch (Exception $exception)
{
    echo '[Error Message] ' . $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

http://www.codediesel.com/php/posting-xml-from-php/

It uses CURL so should be in line with what he's after